Why can we treat samples/permutations as happening one by one?
When considering a sample over some set, we often picture picking elements for the sample one by one. This is used implicitly in many problems. For example, in determining how many $k$-length samples exist over a set of $n$ elements, many standard proofs involve imagining that the sample is being generated one by one, then calculating how many possibilities are left at each "step", then multiplying them all together.
Is there some justification for why we can treat samples as being generated one by one? Or is this just part of the definition of a sample?

You can think of it as counting by grouping. E.g. there are 5 possibilities for the first element in the sample, so we divide the set of all possible samples into 5 groups based on the value of the first element. Then in a similar manner we determine that each group has size $k$, so the overall set has size $5k$. This doesn't assume any ordered choice process is actually used to generate the samples; that's just a convenient way to think about the counting.

That clears things up, thank you!
